# Select 2 columns and count by group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

From a table I need to select 2 column, and group by one column.

```
Result.select(:word_id, :my_url).group(:my_url).count
```

So I wrote that line, but the output is:

```
[...] "https://www.url.com/"=>2 [...]
```

And I need it to be:

```
["https://www.url.com/", 243]=>1
```

I will get this output only if I group by `:my_url and :word_id` but then I will not know how many times the `:my_url` was duplicated.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do two different things by using one line.  And based on that it is impossible.  The group by :my_url is counting how many times it is duplicated not worrying about :word_id which is just being selected(AKA being pulled from the database).  You could do:

```
result = Result.select(:my_url, :word_id)
```

And then with that you can do two different things:

```
result.group(:my_url).count
result.count
```

The other option is maybe rewording your question to why you need this configuration might make it easier to help you.